# Notification Service Extension in iOS works sometimes but stops working other times. User needs to restart device to get it working again

Tags: ios, swift, service, notifications, push

We have an app where the notification service extension works well most of the time. However, sometimes we have noticed that the extension completely stops working even when the notification is sent successfully via the APNS server in production. We do not see even the log from the didReceive() function in that case. The only way we can get the extension working again is after restarting the iPhone.

Trying to understand when this might happen?

Is it something that is throttled by iOS?

Would it happen when the device memory is low or the app is using too much memory?

We have seen the extension crash sometimes due to hitting memory limits, however, the extension process is spawned again when a new notification comes in.

Any kind of help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

We have setup acknowledgment API calls in the notification service extension processing to be notified when the notifications reach the device. So based on that we know how often the devices stop responding with the ACK to sent notifications. It happens seldom with some users and we have to ask them to restart their device to get the extension functional again.

Comment: In these cases are you sure the notification is getting delivered to the phone? If you observe it happening to a phone in your possession, watch the OS logging to see if the handset is receiving the push, but its not being delivered to the extension (if you watch the console while sending a push, you'll be able to spot what Apple components are involved and what they log to the console). It might be worthwhile posting your question on the Apple developer forums, Apple engineers themselves sometimes respond to questions on there (but not very often, but you might get lucky)

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't seen it happen with my device directly. I see it happen on a bunch of user devices. I did raise an issue with Apple Feedback Assistant but let me post it on the forum as well.

Comment: Btw, on the APNS server logs, I can see that the notification was sent successfully. Just FYI.